# Why am I not able to shutdown, log-off and restart after an upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, 13.10

After the update neither my desktop (Asus) nor my laptop (HP) respond to the shut-down, log off or restart commands in the right top tool bar.

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: This is probably a bug.

Comment: I think it is a bug... anyway, you can open a terminal, type `sudo shutdown -h now`, press `enter` and put the password. Is this working?

Comment: Here is a link to the related bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1242907). Please subscribe to the bug and indicate that it affects you, to generate interest in it and be notified of developments.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and found out that even "shutdown" command from terminal didn't help much either.

I am using also Cairo dock and found out that if I try to restart or shutdown from Cairo, it does.

Silly may seems but for me worked.

Comment: I too have been using Cairo dock to restart or shutdown ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 on an Asus desktop running Unity. The problem occurs only after SUSPEND/RESUME, either manual SUSPEND via the Shutdown menu (upper right corner of screen) or by the System Settings/Power suspend timeout after 30 minutes (current SUSPEND setting).

Starting a terminal session and running 'sudo reboot' or 'sudo shutdown now' takes the O/S into single user mode (*I believe*). A Control-D continues the process a little further. At that point, a Control-Alt-Delete reboots to the login screen where the Shutdown menu (upper right corner) is once again available to restart or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Works when you press hardware power button. Then menu will be shown and here you can restart, shut down, and suspend